# python how to install zope.interface on alpine linux

Tags: python, alpine-linux

I have been trying to install zope.interface on alpine linux using pip3 install zope.interface==4.7.1 but I got this error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement zope.interface==4.7.1

Comment: which version of python is it running?

Comment: @drum python 3.7.12